# High cache miss % in azure shared cache preview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, azure

When my application is deployed to azure, my cache miss % jumps from around 0.1% on my local machine to 98.5% on azure.

All i want to do is use the cache service for storing session state. Not holding anything big - an account id (int) and isParent (bool). That's it.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/session-state-caching/) and it all works fine on my localhost, but as soon as I deploy basically nothing gets held in cache. I know it's being lost, because it's inserting null when i submit a form which takes values from the cache when creating a new DB record. This form submission happens literally straight after I login and set the initial values, so I can't imagine the objects are expiring.

I'm using the basic cache offering (128mb). Expiration policy is absolute, and expiry time is 40 mins. Eviction is enabled. My user login is handled by simplemembership - `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` seems to persist fine but I guess that's because it's being held in a cookie.

It's probably worth pointing out as well that i am the ONLY person using this application at this time (i'm the only one who knows about it!)

From searching stackoverflow and google, i'm not really doing anything out of the ordinary but I just can't seem to get it working. This is my first dabble with azure so i might be doing something completely wrong.

If anyone has had anything like this before, i'd be really grateful for any sort of help as this has completely stumped me.